# A little help with $p$-group, normal series, trivial action on factor groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Here is what I assume:

$P$ is a $p$-group and there is a series of subgroups $P_0\unlhd P_1\unlhd \cdots\unlhd P_m = P$ such that $P_i\unlhd P$ for each $0\le i\le m$ and $P_0\le \Phi(P)$. We also have $G\le\text{Aut}(P)$ such that $G$ normalizes each $P_i$. Let $H\le G$ be the subgroup of those $\alpha\in G$ that acts trivially on $P_i/P_{i-1}$ for each $1\le i \le m$.

We note that there is a normal series of $P/\Phi(P)$:

$$1 = P_0\Phi(P)/\Phi(P) \unlhd P_1\Phi(P)/\Phi(P) \unlhd \cdots \unlhd P_m\Phi(P)/\Phi(P) = P/\Phi(P).$$

And here is what I want to show:

- that $H/C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ normalizes $P_i\Phi(P)/\Phi(P)$ for each $i$ and
- that $H/C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ acts trivially on $(P_{i+1}\Phi(P)/\Phi(P))/(P_i\Phi(P)/\Phi(P)) \cong P_{i+1}\Phi(P)/P_i\Phi(P)$ for each $i$.

I think it should be obvious, and I get why $H/C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ normalizes $P_i\Phi(P)/\Phi(P)$ since $H$ acts on $P/\Phi(P)$ and so $H/C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ acts on $P_i\Phi(P)/\Phi(P)$ via

$$xy\Phi(P) \stackrel{\alpha C_H(P/\Phi(P))}{\longmapsto} (x\alpha)(y\alpha)(\Phi(P)\alpha) \in P_i \Phi(P)/\Phi(P),$$
because $x\in P_i$ which is normalized by $\alpha\in H$ and $y\in \Phi(P)$ is normalized by $H$.

But I can't see why $H/C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ acts trivially on $P_{i+1}\Phi(P)/P_i\Phi(P)$... Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write $x^\alpha$ instead of $x\alpha$ so that my holomorphs are multiplicative (you may be writing $P/\Phi(P)$ as row vectors, thinking more additively).

Acting trivially ($\alpha$ on $P_i/P_{i-1}$) means $[x,\alpha] := x^{-1} x^\alpha \in P_{i-1}$ for every $x \in P_i$. Normalizing ($\alpha$ on $P_i$) means $[x,\alpha] \in P_i$ for every $x \in P_i$.

Now $\alpha$ acts trivially on $P_i\Phi(P)/P_{i-1}\Phi(P)$ since $[x, \alpha ] \in P_{i-1}$ for every $x \in P_{i-1}$ and $[y,\alpha] \in \Phi(P)$ for every $y \in \Phi(P)$.

Then just use that $[xy,\alpha] = [x,\alpha][[x,\alpha],y][y,\alpha] \in P_{i-1} P_{i-1} \Phi(P)$ since $y$ (and all of $P$) normalizes $P_{i-1}$.

Comment: So I actually have that $H$ normalizes $P_i\Phi(P)/\Phi(P)$ and acts trivially on $P_i\Phi(P)/P_{i-1}\Phi(P)$? And I don't have to factorize with $C_H(P/\Phi(P))$.

Comment: And since $P_{i-1}\le P_i$ is the fact that $H$ normalizes $P_i$ then a consequence of $H$ acting trivially on $P_i/P_{i-1}$? Since in the latter case, $[x, \alpha] \in P_{i-1}\le P_i$ for every $x\in P_i, \alpha \in H$?

Comment: Right. I mean, you *can* factorize with $C_H(P/\Phi(P))$ which is nice for some things, but you don't have to. -- For $H$ normalizes $P_i$: I think of it more as $G$ normalizes $P_i$, so every subgroup of $G$ also does (normalizing and centralizing/acting trivially can be checked one element $\alpha$ at a time).

Comment: I think you are right too. Acting trivially should always imply normalizing. It also implies normalizing $P_{i-1}$ as well, though I apparently am easily confused on this point. :-)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your answers!